# Multiple jQuery Mobile Count Bubbles

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to have multiple jQuery mobile count bubbles, e.g. you can see here just one bubble displayed next to each item, but i need 6 http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-count.html

is this even possible? or would I use a different function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/kvgUU/

**HTML :**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-count-theme="c" data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">
        Inbox 
        <span class="ui-li-count">12</span>                        
        <span class="ui-li-count count-second">62</span>
        <span class="ui-li-count count-third">62</span>
        <span class="ui-li-count count-fourth">62</span>
        <span class="ui-li-count count-fifth">62</span>
        <span class="ui-li-count count-sixt">62</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        Outbox 
        <span class="ui-li-count">62</span>
        <span class="ui-li-count count-second">0</span></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">
        Drafts 
        <span class="ui-li-count">62</span>
        <span class="ui-li-count count-second">4</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS :**

```
.count-second {
    right: 70px !important;
}

.count-third {
    right: 100px !important;
}

.count-fourth {
    right: 130px !important;
}

.count-fifth {
    right: 160px !important;
}

.count-sixt {
    right: 190px !important;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thanks so much! I have been trying all kinds and yet it was so simple!