# Jquery Mobile - Display Icon With Bubble Count

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

In [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LbDBQ/1/), the goal is to display a bubble count next to each icon.

When attempting to display 2 successive icons with bubbles, the icons are floating left and grouping together.

What CSS is required to display bubble counts immediately after each icon?

HTML

```
<div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
 <a href="#" class="ui-nav-icon" data-role="button" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="notext">Alerts</a>
 <span class="nav-icon ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="font-size:10px;position:static">42</span>

 <a href="#" class="ui-nav-icon" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext">Information</a>
 <span class="nav-icon ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">173</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
a.ui-nav-icon {
    float: left
}
span.nav-icon {
    font-size:11px
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16871990/multiple-jquery-mobile-count-bubbles/16872211#16872211check this

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/yakirmanor/BAat8/) to the solution. It requires wrapping all buttons and count bubbles in a div container.

```
<div class="ui-btn-left" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with 'div' tag.

Try This (Just close div tag after alerticon+bubble and open another div after that)

**CODE IS AS FOLLOW**:

```
<div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
<a href="#" class="ui-nav-icon" data-role="button" data-icon="alert" data-iconpos="notext">Alerts</a>
<span class="nav-icon ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all" style="font-size:10px;position:static">42</span>
 </div>

 <div style="display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap">
<a href="#" class="ui-nav-icon" data-role="button" data-icon="info" data-iconpos="notext">Information</a>
<span class="nav-icon ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">173</span>
</div>
```

I update your jsfiddle too:
http://jsfiddle.net/LbDBQ/8/